# Docker webapp gets stuck when restarted the container

Tags: docker, archlinux

I've installed docker on Arch Linux. Trying to run docker images of web apps, however I can run them only for the very first time. If I stopped the container and run it again, the browser keeps on loading. I have to restart docker service in order to overcome the issue. i.e.

```
docker run --rm --name war -p 8080 -d mvpjava/springboot_docker_tomcat:1.0
curl http://172.17.0.2:8080 ## gives the response.

docker container stop war

docker run --rm --name war -p 8080 -d mvpjava/springboot_docker_tomcat:1.0
curl http://172.17.0.2:8080 ## stuck :(

docker container stop war
sudo systemctl restart docker

docker run --rm --name war -p 8080 -d mvpjava/springboot_docker_tomcat:1.0
curl http://172.17.0.2:8080 ## gives the response again.
```

I've already set `IPForward=kernel` in `/usr/lib/systemd/network/<interface>.network` and the dns configurations done in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`. Also cannot see any errors in docker logs.

Am I missing any configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run the above image looks everything fine but I will mention two things.

```
docker run --rm --name war -p 8080 -d mvpjava/springboot_docker_tomcat:1.0
```

The above command will map any free dynamic port with container `port 8080`. and by doing `curl localhost:8080` will not give response necessary because which port is the map you don't know.

see the dynamic port.
[image]
 so in this case you suppose to curl 32769

inside container after installing curl

[image]

Your docker image does not contain curl I verified it.

Later I assigned static port so its works from the host using curl.

[image]

Then I stop the container and restart but still everything fine.

The issue is from port I am sure.
[image]

You can always find the host port that the exposed container port *(in this case `8080`)* has been mapped to using the command `docker port war` *(replace `war` with the name of the container)*.

The output of the command being something like this: `8080/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32769`. Hence the port `32769` should be used in the host to access the container at port `8080`.